# Speed up one character on a scene?

Tags: animation

Hypothetically, I have 2 characters with a lot of bones.

These 2 characters have different animations, the keyframes are the closest possible to each other

1 character has 10 keyframes and tale 1 second
1 character has 5 keyframes 0.5 seconds

I want to speed up the first character with 10 frames so he takes 0.5 seconds to complete the 10 keyframes but I dont want to speed up the character with 5 keyframes, i want that both characters complete their animations with 0.5 seconds.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so you can either scale down the keyframes in the Dope Sheet, or push the action into the Nonlinear Animation editor and lower down the speed of the strip

Answer (score 0):

I include an example where I animated armature 'metarig.10_frame' so it has several different frames for arms and leg positions, made a copy (named 'metarig.10_frame.to_5_frame'), and then in the timeline I selected all ('a') and scaled ('s') using the mouse.

[image]

You can also use the "Dope Sheet" in the Render workspace to do the same.  I have sometimes had to use the Graph Editor to refine some things like accelerate/decelerate movements to fine tune.

I did not change the animation on armature 'metarig.5_frame'.

[image]